# Can mmonit be run on a port other than 8080?

Tags: monit

I have another service phpmyadmin running at the port 8080. So when I start mmonit, it doesnt start and it gives this error in error log:

```
Creating a serversocket at port 8080 -- Address already in use raised in ServerSocket_new at src/net/ServerSocket.c:58
```

Is it possible to run mmonit at some other port?

Answer (score 0):

In your mmonit config file include a line such as this. There should already be one there, just change the port number:

```
<Connector address="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" port="8081" processors="10" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can run mmonit on another port. In the mmonit config file located here `conf/server.xml`, you can change the port like this (to listen on 8880)

```
<Connector address="*" port="8880" processors="10" />
```

Then restart mmonit